Pandas: set value in rows meeting condition, when data frame has MultiIndex and one index column is a DateTime
I have a data frame with a MultiIndex, and one of the index columns is a DateTime.
df:



symbol
timestamp
trade_count 
foo 




ABC
2023-01-19 00:00:00-05:00
113381.0
0.0



2023-01-20 00:00:00-05:00
79924.0
0.0


...
...
...
...


XYZ
2024-08-08 00:00:00-04:00
92877.0
0.0



2024-08-09 00:00:00-04:00
156009.0
0.0



I would like to say: "for all rows where symbol==ABC and trade_count>100,000, set foo to 123.4". So in other words, in the data shown above, the top row for foo would get 123.4, and it would be left as 0.0 in the other three rows.
I can get a set of Booleans representing whether I want to change the value of foo with:
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'trade_count']>100000




symbol
timestamp
trade_count 




ABC
2023-01-19 00:00:00-05:00
True



2023-01-20 00:00:00-05:00
False



I would have thought that to actually make the change, it would be something like one of these:
df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'foo'].loc[df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'trade_count']>100000] = 123.4
df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'foo'].loc[df['trade_count']>100000] = 123.4
df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'foo'][df['trade_count']>100000] = 123.4

I will admit that I don't fully understand the difference between the above three statements. Something about changing a copy vs. changing the original. All three of those statements run without errors, but when I print the DataFrame, none of the values of foo are actually changed.
My next thought was maybe it's something about the DateTime index column, e.g. maybe there isn't equality between two DateTimes that represent the same value? So I tried this:
bools = (df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'trade_count']>100000).values # Gives a Series of Trues and Falses
df.loc[idx['ABC', :], 'asdf'].loc[bools] = 123.4

But again when I print out df, the value of foo is still 0.0 in every row.
Can anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Use boolean indexing:
m = (df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'ABC') & (df['trade_count'] > 1E5)
df.loc[m, 'foo'] = 123.4

Output:
                                  trade_count    foo
symbol timestamp                                    
ABC    2023-01-19 00:00:00-05:00     113381.0  123.4
       2023-01-20 00:00:00-05:00      79924.0    0.0
XYZ    2024-08-08 00:00:00-04:00      92877.0    0.0
       2024-08-09 00:00:00-04:00     156009.0    0.0

Data used
import pandas as pd

data = {'trade_count': {('ABC',
   pd.Timestamp('2023-01-19 00:00:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')): 113381.0,
  ('ABC', pd.Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')): 79924.0,
  ('XYZ', pd.Timestamp('2024-08-08 00:00:00-0400', tz='UTC-04:00')): 92877.0,
  ('XYZ', pd.Timestamp('2024-08-09 00:00:00-0400', tz='UTC-04:00')): 156009.0},
 'foo': {('ABC', pd.Timestamp('2023-01-19 00:00:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')): 0.0,
  ('ABC', pd.Timestamp('2023-01-20 00:00:00-0500', tz='UTC-05:00')): 0.0,
  ('XYZ', pd.Timestamp('2024-08-08 00:00:00-0400', tz='UTC-04:00')): 0.0,
  ('XYZ', pd.Timestamp('2024-08-09 00:00:00-0400', tz='UTC-04:00')): 0.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.index.names = ['symbol', 'timestamp']

